# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS requirements

Tags: support

Can Intel® Core™ i5-4210U Processor support Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? My laptop is Dell Inspiron 3542.

Comment: Please at least try looking on Google before posting, this is very well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same laptop with Intel® Core™ i5-4210U. It worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just about any x86 system under the sun is supported by Ubuntu.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/620522)

Comment: @KarlRichter - Ummm... yes it does answer the question.

Comment: @AndroidDev only in a very verbatim way of reading - I'd not regard it as helpful either.